# using modulus/fmod and if statement c++

Tags: c++

Problem: you have $1.45 how can we output how many quarters nickels and dimes this is

Output should be 5 quarter 2 dime 1 nickel.

```
double amount = 1.45
double quarter = .25
double dime = .10
double nickel = .05
if(fmod (amount,quarter) == 0)
cout << "your change is"<< amount/quarter << " quarters" ;
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers (`double`) for money.

Comment: Convert to cents ( use int arithmetic for cents because it is discrete value ) as 1.45 * 100 and then quarters = ( 1.45 * 100 ) / (0.25 * 100), dimes = ( (1.45 * 100 ) - quarters * (0.25 * 100 ) ) / (0.10 * 100) and same for nickels

Comment: Why are you using `fmod()`? That will just tell you when the change is just quarters.

Answer (score 1):

Convert to cents ( use int arithmetic for cents because it is discrete value ) as 1.45 * 100 and then

```
int quarters = 145 / 25;
int dimes = ( 145 - quarters * 25 ) / 10;
int nickels = ( 145 - quarters * 25 - dimes * 10 ) / 5;
```